# Dojo function not fired only on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, internet-explorer-7

I am new to dojo. I am debugging a js that's using dojo 1.9.1

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/hash", "dojo/topic"], function (ready, hash, topic) {
    ready(function(){
        try {       
            dimXsl = getDimensionXSLT("somepath.xsl"); // 1
            topic.subscribe("/dojo/hashchange", callback); // 2
            var djConfig = ""; // 3
            djConfig.hashPollFrequnecy = 10; // 4
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error ' + e);
        }
    });        
});

function callback() {// blbla }
```

The above code works for IE8 and above to fire callback(), but not IE7.

My investigations:
I searched Dojo documentation. for version 1.7, the doc https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/hash.html suggests a blank html page. So, I did below:
change js dojo link to 1.7 when href it.
Added blank blank.html in project, and replaced `//3-4` with

```
var dojoConfig = "";
dojoConfig.hashPollFrequnecy = 10;
dojoConfig.dojoBlankHtmlUrl = "/blank.html";
```

Another replacement `//3-4` try was:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    hashPollFrequnecy: 10,
    dojoBlankHtmlUrl: "/blank.html"
};
```

But no luck. I also tried to carry above changes with dojo version 1.9.1, but still no luck.

Any ideas please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement to run on IE7??...It's so old, even cavemen don't use it..lol.  I've had more trouble with IE and dojo than all other browsers combined..I would make them upgrade their browsers or OS (Just say NO to Win XP users).

Comment: @GoinOff Thank you for replying. One of the user sites (IBM connections) is forcing IE7 and it looked weird only in IE7. I am sad..

Comment: Look at console log in ie7 for clues on what is wrong. Good luck..